# Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler null dates

Tags: search, sitecore, lucene.net

I have a property in my index (using the Advanced Database Crawler) for an archive date.

I want to find all items where the date is null or in the future....Date range search will accomplish the second part, but what about the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DateFieldCrawler class, we modified the following code:

```
public override string GetValue()
{
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_field.Value))
 {
     return DateTools.DateToString(DateTime.MinValue, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
 }

 if (FieldTypeManager.GetField(_field) is DateField)
 {
    var dateField = new DateField(_field);

    if(dateField.DateTime > DateTime.MinValue)
    {
       return DateTools.DateToString(dateField.DateTime, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
    }
 }

 return String.Empty;
}
```

By storing this value, we were able to perform the following queries to include null value dates:

```
DateRangeSearchParam.DateRange toFirstDate =
                    new DateRangeSearchParam.DateRange(EVENT_FIRST_DATE,     
                    DateTime.MinValue, toDate.Value);
toFirstDate.InclusiveEnd = false;
eventDates.Add(toFirstDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a *null* search against Lucene. What I've done in the past is to test for emtpy fields and insert the word "EMPTY" in the index. Then when querying the index you need to add a test that checks for the presence (or absence) of that term. It feels kind of dirty doing it that way but that is the only solution I've been able to find or come up with in the 3 years I've been working with Sitecore and Lucene.

Comment: Kyle - we did just that.  Alex Shyba gave me some instructions on how to modify the date field when it is stored in the index - so I replaced the empty value with DateTime.MinValue - that allowed it to work.